# Property of a family of solution of an ODE.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm stuck in solving the following ptoblem:

Show that for each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha \geq 1$ exists $c \in \mathbb{R},$ $ c \geq 0$ so that the solution of the following non linear ODE is equal to $\alpha$ in $1$:

\begin{equation}
   \begin{cases}
   y_c'=\frac{\sqrt c}{ \sqrt{1+y_c^2}}
\\y_c(0)=1
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I would like to solve it without finding esplicitly the solution. Here I write some thoughts I had about this problem:

- For each $c > 0$ the solution is strictly increasing while constant and equal to $1$ if $c=0$
- By observing that

  $\frac{\sqrt c}{ \sqrt{2}y}=\frac{\sqrt c}{ \sqrt{2y^2}} \leq \frac{\sqrt c}{ \sqrt{1+y^2}}\leq \frac{\sqrt c}{ \sqrt{y^2}}=\frac{\sqrt c}{ y}$

if $y \geq 1 $ and by considering the relative Cauchy problems we deduce that:

$2(\frac{\sqrt c}{ \sqrt{2}}x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq y_c(x) \leq 2 (\sqrt{c} x)^{\frac{1}{2}}  $

for every $x \in [0,1]$. In particular we deduce that $y_c(1)$ tends to $+ \infty$ as $c$ tends to $+ \infty$.

Can someone help? :)

Comment: Just a comment: You should rename $y$ on the right-hand side to $y_c$.

Comment: you are right, thanks.